# How to trim whitespace from a string in SASS?

Tags: sass

How do you easily trim a string from whitespaces in sass?
Preferably by choice from the start, the end of the string or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the following sass functions:

```
    // Trims the start/left of the string:
    @function str-trimStart ($str) {
        @if (str-slice($str, 1, 1) == ' ') {
            @return str-trimStart(str-slice($str, 2));
        } @else {
            @return $str;
        }
    }

    // Trims the end/right of the string:
    @function str-trimEnd ($str) {
      @if (str-slice($str, str-length($str), -1) == ' ') {
            @return str-trimEnd(str-slice($str, 1, -2));
        } @else {
            @return $str;
        }
    }

    // Trims both the start and end of the string:
    @function str-trim ($str) {
      @return str-trimStart(str-trimEnd($str));
    }
```

Example of usage:

```
body {
    font-family: str-trim('  Some Font name  ');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more condensed version of the above answer:

```
@function str-trim($string) {
  @if (str-slice($string, 1, 1) == ' ') {
    @return str-trim(str-slice($string, 2));
  } @else if (str-slice($string, str-length($string), -1) == ' ') {
    @return str-trim(str-slice($string, 1, -2));
  } @else {
    @return $string;
  }
}
```